# Car alignment and tire wear mismatch

Tags: tires, alignment

I've recently changed two of my tires on my Honda Civic EX-T 2016. These tires (front and back of the passenger's side) kept losing air consistently, becoming flat after 1 week in parking. I bought two new ones that went in the rear and the rear one (driver's side) went in the front. I also did a wheel alignment at PepBoys (the report from the alignment machine shows that all is good).
However, the steering wheel is tilted to the side a bit (around 3-5 degrees) and the car still loses alignment on the highway after ~50 meters (it takes bigger distance when driving slower). The two front tires have a different wear (around 4mm vs 6mm - came when I bought the car). Could this be the misalignment issue and I just need to buy two more new tires?

Comment: Welcome to Motor Vehicle Maintenance & Repair! Part of the alignment process is to ensure the steering wheel is straight when the tech is finished. If that part of it wasn't done correctly, what else could possibly be wrong?